# Safely edit xml in landscape mode

Tags: android, xml

I have an activity in my application that i want accessible both for portrait and landscape mode. My question is, can I edit my xml file safely when i change the view to landscape in Eclipse, without it affecting my portrait mode? Or do I need a whole new layout file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a extra Layout with the same Name in `res/layout_land`. This Layout is choosen in Landscape. Simply switch to Landscape Mode in XML Editor only affects the rendering in your editor and does nothing else so you can't make Landscape Layout specific changes in the same Layoutfile.

PS: If the folder `layout_land` does not exist, simply create it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I name all my view in the land layout as the views in the normal layout?

Comment: Yes they have to have exactly the same name. Android uses a lot "convention over configuration" in its resource system

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. In your manifest

You dont't need to create new activity xml

```
<activity
             android:name=".YourActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

There is no affecting your portrait mode

Comment: @ErikSoderstrom ya i'm sure about that if you have doubt check with model example..